# partial update json field in postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

In Postgres I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE storehouse
(
  user_id bigint NOT NULL,
  capacity integer NOT NULL,
  storehouse json NOT NULL,
  last_modified timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT storehouse_pkey PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
)
```

And `storehouse.storehouse` is storing data like this:

```
{
    "slots":[
        {
            "slot" : 1,
            "id" : 938
        },
        {
            "slot" : 2,
            "id" : 127
        },
    ]
}
```

The thing is, I want to update `storehouse.storehouse.slots[2]`, but I do not have an idea on how to do it.

I know how to alter the entire `storehouse.storehouse` field, but I am wondering since Postgres supports `json` type, it should support partial modify, otherwise that would be no difference between `json` type and `text` type. (I know `json` type also has type validation which is differ to `text`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSON indexing and partial updates are not currently supported. The JSON support in PostgreSQL 9.2 is rudimentary, limited to validating JSON and to converting rows and arrays to JSON. Internally, `json` is indeed pretty much just `text`.

There's ongoing work for enhancements like partial updates,indexing, etc. No matter what, though, PostgreSQL won't be able to avoid rewriting the whole row when part of a JSON value changes, because that's inherent to the MVCC model of concurrency. The only way to make that possible would be to split JSON values out into multiple tuples in a side relation, like TOAST tables - something that's possible, but likely to perform poorly and that's very far from being considered at this point.

As Chris Travers points out, you *can* use PL/V8 functions or functions in other languages with json support like Perl or Python to extract values, then create expression indexes on those functions.

Comment: I would just add that functions written in plv8js may be a good way to manage the update process.  One could probably write a narrow function in plperlu that would do the same.

Comment: The latest postgres does support this feature, look at the answer below

Answer (score 4):

Since PostgreSQL 9.5, there a function called [`jsonb_set`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What's_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.5#jsonb_set_function) which takes as input parameters:

- a JSON object
- an array indicating the path (keys and subkeys)
- the new value to be stored (also a JSON object)

Example:

```
 # SELECT jsonb_set('{"name": "James", "contact": {"phone": "01234 567890", "fax": "01987 543210"}}'::jsonb,
            '{contact,phone}',
            '"07900 112233"'::jsonb);
                                  jsonb_replace                                  
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  {"name": "James", "contact": {"fax": "01987 543210", "phone": "07900 112233"}}
 (1 row)
```